SET Command to Sort (Alphabetize & Ascendeing numberical order)
In my data set, I have lists of comma separated values (JSON) within MySQL data fields.
Example, in my inventory table I have three columns, first an id column then two more called eligible_vehicle_type and weight_class. These are example JSON-ified values within this table, as you can see it is a list of things:
id = 1
eligible_vehicle_type= ["c","b","a"]
weight_class = ["3","2","1"]

I need a set command that will produce this result:
vehicles = ["a","b","c"] (for string values)
weight_class = ["1","2","3"] (for integer values), for id 1.

Is this feasible with a SET command?

I don't think so. You would have to explode the array using JSON_TABLE() and then aggregate it with JSON_ARRAYAGG(), but you can't control the order if you do this, because MySQL subquery optimization eliminates any ORDER BY clause if you do aggregation.

I suggest you should not be storing data in JSON if you want to do this type of operation.

Why are your integer values in strings? When you order them, you'll need to convert to integer to get correct ordering.

@BillKarwin JSON_ARRAYAGG() allows an over_clause, which can contain ORDER BY

@Barmar Yes, but that's for a window function. It won't reduce the rows of the JSON_TABLE(), because it isn't aggregation.
